# Toggle the background using local storage

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themes, local-storage, toggle

My theme is getting changed once page is refreshed. Please help me to get the page with same style once we change the theme (after refresh the page).

Demo.
https://jsfiddle.net/aopf97z3/1/

The current class is not appearing once the page is refreshed.
Code:

```
<body>
    <div class="theme_change">Change Your Theme</div>    
    <div class="content">The below content is the Test content</div>    
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
}
.content {
  background:#f00;
  color:#fff;
}
.black_theme {
  background:#2180c7;
  color:#000;
}
```

Script:

```
$('.theme_change').on('click', function() { 
    $('body').toggleClass('black_theme');       
    $('this').toggle(); 
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it won't do, you would need to save it in local storage or a cookie and then load it out when you refresh

Comment: Thanks for your input Pete.

However, I achieve the above one theme displays same color after page refresh. But the problem is not able switch the original theme.due to local storage. It will work fine after clear cache. demo https://jsfiddle.net/aopf97z3/3/